# Sort Numbers After Their Values

Tags: calculations, sorting, latex3

Consider the numbers

> 2^4, 4^2, 3^2, and 5^2

Is it possible to make LaTeX calculate the values of these numbers and then arrange then automatically according to their values?

That is, in this particular case, I would like to get the output

> 3^2, 2^4, 4^2, and 5^2

P.S. It doesn't have to be a LaTeX 3 solution.

Comment: Do you have a fixed amount of numbers you want to calculate and sort in this way or does it need to by dynamic, for any amount of numbers?

Comment: @Big-Blue It should be dynamic. (Sorry, I completely overlooked your question.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easy with [`xparse`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and [`expl3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sortnumberlist}{m}
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_svend_numberlist_clist { #1 }
  \clist_sort:Nn \l_svend_numberlist_clist
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > ##2 }
     {
      \sort_return_swapped:
     }
     {
      \sort_return_same:
     }
   }
  \clist_clear:N \l_svend_printnumberlist_clist
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_svend_numberlist_clist
   {
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_svend_printnumberlist_clist { $##1$ }
   }
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_svend_printnumberlist_clist { ~and~ }{ ,~ }{ ,~and~ }
 }
\clist_new:N \l_svend_printnumberlist_clist
\clist_new:N \l_svend_numberlist_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sortnumberlist{2^4, 4^2, 3^2, 5^2, 13, 25-1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does someone know why `l3sort` isn’t documented in `source3.pdf`?

Comment: @Tobi It's still in the experimental branch.